# Collapsing a List<double[][]> to a double[][]

Tags: java, arrays, list

I have a variable of type `List<double[][]>`

An example of what would be in the list is as follows (with each new line being a list element):

```
{ {1.0,0.0,0.0}, {0.0,0.0,0.0} }
{ {0.0,0.0,0.0}, {1.0,0.0,0.0}, {0.0,1.0,0.0} }
```

The outcome I need to achieve is a `double[][]` with all the elements from the list as such (using the same values as above):

```
{ {1.0,0.0,0.0}, {0.0,0.0,0.0}, {0.0,0.0,0.0}, {1.0,0.0,0.0}, {0.0,1.0,0.0} }
```

The size of the inner most array will always be the same. However, the outter array varies in size.

I'd really appreciate some help on this one, I seem to think the solution is easy but I just can't come up with it!

Comment: So you want an array...of `double[][]`.  Right?

Comment: Do your `double[][]` arrays in `List` have the same, fixed dimensions?

Comment: I've added array size details to the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is what the Streaming API's `flatMap` is for:

```
List<double[][]> list = Arrays.asList(
        new double[][]{{1.0, 0.0, 0.0}, {0.0, 0.0, 0.0}},
        new double[][]{{0.0, 0.0, 0.0}, {1.0, 0.0, 0.0}, {0.0, 1.0, 0.0}});

double[][] result = list.stream()
        .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
        .toArray(double[][]::new);
```

Produces `{ {1.0,0.0,0.0}, {0.0,0.0,0.0}, {0.0,0.0,0.0}, {1.0,0.0,0.0}, {0.0,1.0,0.0} }`

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a go and let you know how I get on.

Answer (score 4):

```
List<double[][]> list;

//calculate the length of the array (sum of the length of all double[][]s in the list)
int resultLen = 0;
for(double[][] d : list)
    resultLen += d.length;

double[][] result = new double[resultLen][];

//copy all double[]s that are in the list (wrapped into double[][]s)
//into the new double[][]
int index = 0;
for(double[][] d : list)
    for(double[] a : d)
        result[index++] = a;

return result;
```

Comment: For the above example by Paul you need to declare the array as:

  double[][] result = new double[resultLen][];

Comment: I've fixed it. There were only two characters missing.

Comment: Yes it works fine, I'll upvote you. I should add that it will work fine if the inner array dimensions differ as we are not sizing the inner array in the declaration of result.